How to completely stop a particle with a given generalized momentum?
I have the following question. In order to stop a particle with a given generalized momentum, do I need to counter only the mechanical momentum, or the whole generalized momentum?
Could someone please help me with an answer?
If the answer is that I need to counter the whole generalized momentum, then why isn't it called "true momentum"? At least my intuition tells me that the true momentum of a particle is the momentum needed to completely stop it from moving.
I am thankful for the help anyone could give.

It seems you want to understand more about generalized momentum itself, maybe you should alter the question a bit to also add that to the requirements of an answer.

Illustrate your question by a bead sliding on a frictionless ring. Why do you say  vanishing  generalized momentum is different than  vanishing mechanical momentum?

You can also illustrate a situation where the question doesn't quite make sense in the intuitive way you ask for. The fields that make up QFT all have generalized momentum but what would it even mean to say to stop a field completely that has such a momentum to it? This is why I mentioned maybe it's better if you first gain a deeper understanding of what generalized momentum is.
